# How to extend a network protocol for new features?

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols

I want to design a protocol for communicating between a client and a server for sending audio/video. How to extend it for new features? What is the most common way to do this?

My thought is to use a version number field in the protocol and deserialize the header (which implement this protocol) according to this number. Is it the right way to do it?

Comment: The number one rule to extensible protocols: Don't use binary protocols, use text. Rule two: If you only want to send data (and not commands) then use nested markup-based protocols, XML or JSON can be extended more or less indefinitely without worrying about things like version numbering schemes.

Comment: Thanks, @JoachimPileborg. I like the idea of using nested markup based protocols, but doesn't it change the total number of bytes transmitted as well? When unpacking a received data buffer, how can I know if a new feature is supported if I don't have a version number? Even if I used XML or JSON?

Comment: Regarding new versions in a markup-based protocol, you simply add new markup for the new data. If the data doesn't have the new markup it's from an old client or server, and if an old client/server receives markup it doesn't know about it simply ignores it.

Comment: Many thanks, @JoachimPileborg. If you have written the above in the answer section, I would definitely mark it as the answer to the question.